# What should I use straight FK fields or Entity objects?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm newbie with Hibernate and I don't which is the best approach for doing this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "alumno")
public class Alumno implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "salon_id")
    private Integer salonId;

}
```

Where salonId field is mapped to a database field which is a fk refering to Salon table id or this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "alumno")
public class Alumno implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    private Salon salon;

}
```

Which are the advantages of one vs the other?

Comment: Sorry, I edited them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should of course use the second one. The whole point of entities and ORM is to be able to load a graph of objects from the database and navigate through the object graph:

```
Alumno alumno = em.find(Alumno.class, id);
Salon salon = alumno.getSalon();
```

In this case, you would need a `@ManyToOne` or `@OneToOne` annotation on your salon field (depending on the actual cardinality of the association).

Comment: When should I use the other approach?

Comment: I can't find any justification for using the other approach.

Comment: To do in this way would load all the salon properties right? Or is it just going to load the join column value?

Comment: Read the hibernate documentation. It will load the Salon in the OneToOne is EAGER (and it is EAGER by default). If you make it LAZY, then it will only load the FK, and will load the Salon properties when calling a method on the Salon object.